# Is it still possible for one person to make a complete game?

Tags: development-speed

Is it still possible for one person to design and develop a complete game with all audio/visual/game mechanics aspects in place (complete package). I have some interest in game development, but don’t want to hire anyone... but wondering if it’s even feasible anymore to go solo.

Comment: A [little bit of research](https://www.google.com/search?q=games+made+by+one+person) could have answered this.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: It depends on the scope of your game. It's entirely possible for one person to create a decent game, but if you want it to be profitable, you will have to wear a lot of hats: designer, programmer, artist, audio engineer, marketing exec, and tester. Not only that, you will have to plan and manage your own project.

You also have to consider the timescales involved. Every feature will require new code, testing, potentially new assets, and will need to be designed in such a way as to be maintainable. All this takes time, so you have to decide how much time you have to devote to your project.

So to summarise:

You can totally do games as a solo developer, but don't expect to be able to produce a AAA game any time soon. Hobby/web games are totally doable within reasonable timescales and cost.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is  possible, if you have the motivation needed to do it, it won't be easy I can tell you, but if you work hard at it you will succeed. And another important thing, think simple don't try to do the biggest game of your career, make something simple.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the scale of your game.  Monsters like "Call of Duty" require thousands of person-years.  You don't have that long.  OTOH, if you start
with the right tools (which you already know how to use), a new game can be done in day (if it's simple enough).

You should also consider your actual goal.  If making the game is an end in itself, it's a very different thing than if you want thousands of happy users.